# Magento 2.3 : change store view bypass from url

Tags: magento2.3, store-view, store-switcher

i want to change my store view from url  is it possible ?

so I just type url : http:// xxx. com/urltochangestoreview

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide more details.

Comment: @Jai hi, I just updated my question

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please provide detail information what you are trying to achieve. You are new here so I am trying to help you so that your question dont get deleted. For that you need to provide full details.Good luck